# Background image is moving on iPad and iPhone

Tags: ios, css, iphone, ipad

I have a webpage: www.kvf.fo/vit and when visiting it on an iPad or iPhone, the background-image is slightly movable or draggable, so the the background-color is showing (behind). This is only if you try to drag at the top or at the bottom, or side to side. Any have a solution to this?

CSS Code

```
body {
    background-color: #0083B3;
    background-image: url('../images/bakgrundin_jol3.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: left top;
    color: white;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: disable touch events when that background is touched, other wise, enbable touch events on other uielemeents

Comment: Tried that without any luck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't be possible because the background-image is sized for your screen size.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand?

Comment: If you set a background-image for your html it is loaded with the width of your device. If you now move it with a touchscreen or a multi-touch trackpad, the width is moved to side thus you see the "thing" behind, your background-color. I don't know if you have a Mac, but if you have, you will have the same problem.

Maybe this sounds a bit difficult but as far as I know this won't work without any hacks.

Cheers

Comment: Hey, what actually could work is to set the beginning of a div to -10 at all sides. If you give it then your background image it could be that you don't see your background.

Comment: Oh, but I see you have solved your problem otherwise